# Update document if a field in last element in array does not equal value

Tags: mongodb, updates

I wonder how I should match a document by last element in an Array in mongodb document.
Say I want to update a specific document with new data if a field in last element of array is not equal some specific value.
I know that I can do this to check if a field in Array does not contain that value already:

```
myTable.update({ Thing: thisThing, 
                 'myArray.Element': {$ne: parseInt(thisValue)} }, ...)
```

But how should one check that the last `Element` (`myArray.Element`) in `myArray` is not equal to `thisValue`?
Note that I want to do this with `find`and **not** `aggregate`.

Best Regards

Comment: I suppose arrays can have different or unknown lengths?

Comment: @dgiugg Yes thats correct

Comment: I guess I could use $slice

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have collection names, looking like this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58de74f8c1bb7f4256adf32c"),
    "user" : "John",
    "list_friends" : [ 
        "Alice", 
        "Bob"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58de75d3c1bb7f4256adf32d"),
    "user" : "Pop",
    "list_friends" : [ 
        "Eve", 
        "Oscar"
    ]
}
```

Now, let's say we want to change "user" field to "Updated" for all users whose last friend name is different than "Oscar" (in this case that is John). This query:

```
db.getCollection('names').update({$where: "this.list_friends[this.list_friends.length - 1] !== 'Oscar'"}, {"$set": {"user": "Updated"}})
```

modifies the collection and the final result is:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58de74f8c1bb7f4256adf32c"),
    "user" : "Updated",
    "list_friends" : [ 
        "Alice", 
        "Bob"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58de75d3c1bb7f4256adf32d"),
    "user" : "Pop",
    "list_friends" : [ 
        "Eve", 
        "Oscar"
    ]
}
```

I tested the solution using Mongo 3.2, I am not sure if it works for older versions.

Comment: $where is to slow:/ $slice could be a solution:)

Comment: @user1665355 I wasn't sure from the question details that you wanted something more efficient. You're right, $where is slow.

Comment: But you dont know about any other solution? :)

Comment: @user1665355 not without aggregate :)

Comment: What if the elements in the array is not plain, for example: in 1,['Alice' : {'age': 3}, 'Bob' : {'age' : 50}]; in 2 ['Eve': { 'age' : 7},  'Oscar' : { 'age' : 10}].  And I want to find the documents, which has the last friend's age larger than 20, which is the doc 1 in here.